# Handling software versions in Chef recipes

Tags: deployment, chef-infra, devops, continuous-deployment

I'm fairly new to Chef and I'm looking to dynamically handle versioning for each release of our software in the recipe which downloads and installs the software.

For example, how could I download version 2.17.0 of our software, and the following deployment 2.18.0 without having to modify the recipes themselves each week?

I think attributes for the nodes will allow me to do this if accessed in the recipes themselves? Although I'm not sure if this is the chef way or doing things or best practice...

```
aws_s3_file "C:\\Users\\our_software_VERSION.exe do
    bucket 'awsbucket'
    remote_path 'software/our_software_VERSION.exe'
    region 'eu-west-1'
    aws_access_key *
    aws_secret_access_key creds *
    action :create_if_missing
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, node attributes are definitely an option. `remote_path "software/our_software_#{node["myapp"]["version"]}.exe"`.

You could also use a data bag item, depending on the situation, but attributes set in a role or env are probably best.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html here. You will find the answer.